# CSS position icon to top right of table

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to CSS. I have a table on my page which has a width of 70%. I need to position a small icon just above the right side of the table so that the icon is aligned with the right margin of the table below it. How can I achieve this?

So generically this question would be how to position elements relative to the position of other elements on a page using CSS?

Thanks,
Calvin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi now you can do this easily throw **Position** Give to `Parent Position Relative` and `child to give position Absolute` and do **top right** according to your layout

Live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/srgJh/

Answer (score 4):

In CSS you should write:

```
.myclass {
    position:relative;
}
```

or

```
<img style="position:relative;" />
```

then you can control position by "top", "left", "right", "bottom" statement. Example:

```
<img src="position: relative; top: 20px;" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still not understanding how this tells the image to be relative to the table?

Comment: image should actually be positioned absoute, and table positioned relative

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="position:relative;float:left;overflow:hidden">
<table>
...
</table>
<div class="icon"></div>
</div>

.icon {
position:absolute;
width:10px;
height:10px;
top:0;
right:0; 
}
```

if want the icon be outside the table write values with minus, for ex:

```
top:-10px; /* above the table */
right:-10px; /* on the right side the table */
```

Answer (score 1):

Give This css :

```
.classname {
    position:relative;
}
```

i hope you problem will be solve

Comment: Applying above syntax in my CSS, it works like a charm. I think I need to explore more attributes of CSS. Thanks Rushi

Answer (score 0):

The guys above have answered the question, but if you want to know how it works, try looking at:
http://www.tizag.com/cssT/position.php

Also you should consider using Divs instead of tables, when creating layout of the entire page:
http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmldiv.php